# Save way to override sensitive data on the heap

Tags: c++, security, passwords, password-protection

Let's say we have a password, saved as a char array `char m_topSecretPassword[128];`. We ask the user to enter the password and then use it in some way (for example to connect to a database). Is there some save way to make absolutly sure that the password is removed from memory after usage?

My first thought was that we could just iterate over the array and set every value to 0 or some random number. However, the optimizer could optimize this away, leaving our unchanged password in memory until something on the system overrides it, which could take quite a lot of time.

Then I thought about using volatile but this could slow down the program.

We could do it with assembler but that would destroy portability.

Is there some better way?

Comment: Note that [volatile doesn't necessarily work anyway](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2014-09-04-how-to-zero-a-buffer.html). C11 introduces `memset_s`, but there's no portable way in older C dialects; I don't know about C++.

Comment: *"could slow down"* Alright, this is not ultra relevant as `volatile` is not the right tool here to begin with, but that statement is prove you did not do your homework. Something either is too slow or it isn't, guessing about performance is *extremely* inaccurate.

Comment: @Gilles memset_s only makes sure that no buffer overflow occurs (and some other things), it does not make sure that the call is not optimized away. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset

Comment: @Brotcrunsher That's not true, either: *"memset may be optimized away (under the as-if rules) if the object modified by this function is not accessed again for the rest of its lifetime (e.g. gcc bug 8537). For that reason, this function cannot be used to scrub memory (e.g. to fill an array that stored a password with zeroes). This optimization is prohibited for memset_s: it is guaranteed to perform the memory write."* From the very page you linked.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You are right.

Comment: @Gilles Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I would probably use a function pointer to an erase function so the optimizer can not eradicate it. Maybe make sure the function pointer points to a function in its own, separate TU (make it a library) to be sure.

Comment: @Galik That doesn't really work either, as the article linked by Gilles aptly explains.

Comment: @BaummitAugen That article seems to only fail if you use `memset` If you write your own erase function the compiler can not know.

Comment: @Galik Its main point is that there is no portable way to override stuff in CPU cache. Anyways, "writing your own" is a wrong approach, too, given LTO and inlining through function pointers (llvm is already pretty good on that one) will probably catch up with you sooner or later.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Well I would compile without LTO as well.

Comment: @Galik Meh, sooner or later someone will compile your code with LTO; relying on missed optimizations for code correctness is not a good idea IMO.